# Strange "misuse of aggregate: max()" error in SQLite

Tags: select, sqlite, where-clause

I have SQLite table with very simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `id` INTEGER, `val` TEXT )
```

I want to select only max id where `val` field value is equal to string "test_id":

```
SELECT max(id) AS test_id FROM test WHERE val = "test_id"  // (1)
```

Please note that I use "**test_id**" string in `WHERE` and **test_id** as custom column name. I get error:

```
misuse of aggregate: max(): SELECT max(id) AS test_id FROM test WHERE val = "test_id"
```

If I change `max(id) AS test_id` to `max(id) AS test_id2` or `WHERE val = "test_id"` to `WHERE val = "test_id_something"` - all works.

In MySQL I have no errors with original SELECT **(1)**. Corrected versions works well to.
What is I'm doing wrong? Is it not allowed to use same text in `WHERE` and as column name in SQLite?

Comment: `WHERE` can not use aggregate functions even through aliases

Comment: change `"test_id"` to `'test_id'` (double quote to single quote) it works too.

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to find? is it the row with the highest id whose value = "tast_value"

Comment: @AryedovEidelman imagine that "val" field describe row type. For example, it can be "Book", "CD", "Film". If I want to find highest id where type is "CD" I need something like: SELECT max(id) AS Book FROM test WHERE val = "Book"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, double quotes are used to refer to column/table names, and `test_id` indeed is a column name. Strings are delimited with single quotes:

```
SELECT max(id) AS test_id FROM test WHERE val = 'test_id'
```

SQLite allows double quotes for strings in order to be bug-compatible with MySQL, but when in doubt, it has to choose the standard interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question

> If I change max(id) AS test_id to max(id) AS test_id2 or WHERE val = "test_id" to WHERE val = "test_id_something" - all works.

`WHERE val = "test_id"` references `max(id) AS test_id`. you need to use diffrent names. try this

```
SELECT max(id) AS max_id FROM test WHERE val = "some_value"
```

`misuse of aggregate: max():` is the normal result of using aggregate functions (`AVG`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`...) in a `WHERE` clause

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b28b3/11